# Issue in conplex

Tags: python

I write this simple code,but I catch multiple errors.

> v0[t]=abs(values_list[k]-list(x1)) TypeError: unsupported operand
> type(s) for -: 'complex' and 'list'

I appreciate any help.

```
x1=[1.5+1.2j]
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
mapping = {
          (0,0,0,0) : -3-3j,
          (0,0,0,1) : -3-1j,
          }  
modulation=4
values= mapping.values()# extract values
values_list = list(values)# tuple to list
print(values_list[0])
v0=[0,0]
t=0
for k in  range(2):
 v0[t]=abs(values_list[k]-list(x1)) 
 print(k)
```

Comment: How do you intend on subtracting a list from a number?

Answer (score 0):

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'complex' and 'list'
```

This mean you tried to subtract `list` from `complex` number, you are doing:

```
x1=[1.5+1.2j]
```

...

```
v0[t]=abs(values_list[k]-list(x1))
```

I suppose `x1` should be `complex`. Then change first to `x1=1.5+1.2j` (currently this is `list` with one `complex`) and second to `v0[t]=abs(values_list[k]-x1)`.